# Help me simplify: $\cos(−\theta) + \tan(−\theta) \sin(−\theta)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Simplify $$\cos(−\theta) + \tan(−\theta) \sin(−\theta)$$ to one term with no negative thetas.

Comment: Since it isn't an equation, suggest changing title to "... simplify this expression" or better to include trig as in "..simplify this trig expression"

Comment: I'm assuming that $\sin(-x)$ should be $\sin(-\theta)$ ? Otherwise all these lovely answers need to be revised

Comment: @rt6 Yes I think that's safe assumption since a two variable function could not be made into one term usually.

Answer (score 5):

Since cos is even and each of sine, tan is odd, the function is same as $\cos \theta +\tan \theta \sin \theta.$ Putting s for sine and c for cosine this is $$c+(s/c)s=c+s^2/c=\frac{c^2+s^2}{c}=\frac{1}{c}=\sec \theta.$$

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to use that $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$, $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$ and that $\tan(-x)=-\tan(x)$. Then write $\tan$ in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$ and try using $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$.

Comment: Actually, $\tan(-x)=-\tan(x)$.